# Automatic formatting of axis in Excel stacked bar chart to start at start date?

Tags: microsoft-excel, charts, automation, axis, gantt

I have used this blog https://peltiertech.com/excel-gantt-charts/#comment-1455520 to create a Gantt chart in Excel that acts as a template for others to input their information (i.e. tasks, start dates, duration etc) and easily produce a Gantt chart.

This issue I have is that I have formatted the minimum on the x-axis to be 1st January 2018, which is 43101 in general format, like so:

Minimum value for x axis being 1st January 2018
[image]

But this means that if a user wishes to start the Gantt chart at a different point in time, say April 1st 2018, then there is a massive blank space before it starts.

Empty space between 1st Jan and 1st April
[image]
How can I get the chart to automatically format based on whatever date is inputted?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

In the Axis minimum and maximum value.. notice the value 43101 & 43473 ? both are the Excel date-time code.

To seek which date does 43101 corresponds to, just type it in any empty excel cell. Then r-click > cell format > "date". See? 1 Jan 2018 is the date represented by this value. Do the same for 43473 and you get the idea.

So how to get the Excel date-time code for 1 Apr 2018?  Just type in `=value(date(2018,4,1))` in any cell. Use that value to key in the Axis minimum.

Hope this helps.. (:

Comment: Thanks for replying but unfortunately I know how to find what to put in. It is more about having it automatically update the minimum axis without someone having to change it every time a different date is used. This will be going to many non-technical people and I don't want them to have to faff around trying to get it to format correctly so would rather it automatically updated it for them.

Comment: I see.. sorry about that..  couldn't help it. || If I were in your shoe, I'll type a separate, clear instruction to the users to do this simple fix.. (by attaching a a formula in the file just for this) . || Hope you'll find a solution though. ( :